# Unknown server tag 'asp:Silverlight'

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I am getting the error above when I run a solution developed in Visual Studio 2010 and using Silverlight 4.  Does anyone know the solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `asp:Silverlight` tag was removed from the SDK on release of Silverlight 3.  You need to be using the html `<object>` tag directly.  Review the contents of the test host page the Visual Studio creates when you create a new Silverlight solution.

Comment: This answer isn't very helpful. I am not a silverlight dev and was trying to get a silverlight example to compile and execute. I wasn't able to simply replace the asp:Silverlight tag with object ...